# two databases one column to link to location database with multiple columns to create a drill down

Tags: powerbi

I have a file with report data which includes the location the report was filed. I have a hierarchy built that includes region, state, city, neighborhood in columns A, B, C,D. I need to figure out how to link the report "location" with the result in A, B, C or D.

```
Report Number |Location| Record Title| Record Status
EMOC-18-3   | Belfield Gas Plant - PSM |Bypassing PICO controller on H-8100 | Canceled
EMOC-18-30 |North District Gathering - Hiawatha |   Insulated Fuel Gas |Line at Trail Station   |Completed 
EMOC-18-31 North District Gathering - Hiawatha  Vermillion Creek Compressor Recycle Line    Ready To Start Up 
EMOC-18-33 |    San Diego   |California Marketing Terminals - Shell Additive change from NEMO 1124e and 1125 to NEMO 1127 and 1128, respectively |  Completed
```

Result I'm hoping for would sum up the report with all positive results for 
Region (includes sum of all child results in B, C, D) and further drilldown city includes city + neighborhood(C&D) etc.

I am new to powerbi and was told to create a location relationship and then do a drilldown, but this isnt really working. I'm trying to figure out if I need to code something, but do not know how to code. I've tried creating v-lookups in Excel but the logic ended up stumping me. I ended up counting how many of each item I had but I'm not sure how to link them as a sum to be able to count the hierarchy of the locaitons below it.

Result I'm hoping for would sum up the report with all positive results for 
Region (includes sum of all child results in B, C, D) and further drilldown city includes city + neighborhood(C&D) etc.

Comment: Can you give some sample data (comma separated, including column headers is ok) so we understand better what you are looking for

Comment: Report File |Location| Record Title| Record Status|

Comment: So you have only one table with 4 columns? I want to help but can only do this if you provide the right data. There is no data in the table?

Comment: trying to figure out how to upload. Report File  = Report Number |Location| Record Title| Record Status|     
 EMOC-18-3 | Belfield Gas Plant - PSM |Bypassing PICO controller on H-8100 | Canceled
EMOC-18-30 |North District Gathering - Hiawatha  | Insulated Fuel Gas |Line at Trail Station |Completed
EMOC-18-31 North District Gathering - Hiawatha Vermillion Creek Compressor Recycle Line Ready To Start Up
EMOC-18-33 | San Diego |California Marketing Terminals -  Shell Additive change from NEMO 1124e and 1125 to NEMO 1127 and 1128, respectively | Completed

Comment: the location in the first will be in one of these five columns  depedning on the location  in the report.  Region|District|Sub-District| Asset layer 1| asset 2|asset 3| Asset 4

Comment: ex. Mid-Con| Northern Great Plains |Central District NGP |Central District LACTS NGP |Charlson Gathering  |Norby 9-20H-1    or second locaiton with fewer children TT&S| West Coast| Southern California| San Diego

Comment: the result I need is for ex. high level sum:  TT&S =1 drill down each level at a time until you could see that it was San Diego that was the 1, but if hypothetically some of the samples I sent included other locations in given hierarchy it would be greater so TT&S would include all positive hits within its tree that match the location column in the report file.

Comment: @sporty9xterra - it's very hard to understand your data and the desired results from the comments. Could you add the data sample and outcome examples to you question, properly formatted?

Comment: You can use the **[edit]** link at the bottom of your post to update it, like adding that table you've been putting in the comments. Avoid putting additional info in the comments as comments do not have formatting which makes it hard to read.